# How do I upload an image on Python using Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am doing GUI programming using Tkinter on Python. I am using the grid manager to make widgets. I have created several buttons and I want to upload an image on top of them. When I enter this code, it gives me an `escape sequence error`.

I heard using PIL is not a good idea? Is that true?

```
cookImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/C:\Users\terimaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\cook.gif")
```

Comment: please show the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows filenames must be entered as raw strings:

```
cookImage = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\terimaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\cook.gif")
```

This applies to all of Python, not just PIL.

Comment: _must_ is a rather strong term. You can also use forward slashes, or backwards slashes that are escaped with backslashes.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fair enough, but raw strings are the cleanest way. I never recommend forward slashes since they only mostly work.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
path = r"a string with the path of the photo"
```

Note the `r` prefix, it means a raw string.

```
...
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file=path))
label = tk.Label(root, image = img)
label.something() #pack/grid/place
...
```

The path can be:

- Absolute (`"C:\Users\terimaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\cook.gif"`)
- Relative (`"\cook.gif"`, depends on where the Python code is)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an [image file](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html) that is exactly what you want, just open it with `BitmapImage` or `PhotoImage`.  Note that Tcl/Tk 8.6, which you should have with 3.6 on Windows, also reads .png files.  On Windows, prefix the filename with 'r' or use forward slashes: 'C:/User/...'.

The actual PIL package is no longer maintained and only works on 2.x.  That is what a new user should not use.  The compatible successor, `pillow` (installed for instance with `python -m pip install pillow`) is actively maintained and works with 3.x.  The compatibility extends to the import statement: `import PIL` imports pillow.  Pillows allows one to manipulate images and to convert many formats to tk format (the ImageTk class).

Answer (score 0):

this is exact code which is most help for move image

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os, shutil

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root,self).__init__()
        self.title("thinter Dialog Widget")
        self.minsize(640,400)

        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,text="Open A File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column=0,row=1,padx= 20, pady= 20)
        self.btton()

    def btton(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text="Browse Afile", command=self.fileDailog)
        self.button.grid(column=1,row=1)
    def fileDailog(self):
        self.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title="Select A File",filetype=(("jpeg","*.jpg"),("png","*.png")))
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text="")
        self.label.grid(column =1,row = 2)
        self.label.configure(text = self.fileName)
        os.chdir('e:\\')
        os.system('mkdir BACKUP')
        shutil.move(self.fileName,'e:\\')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

you could not move image to c drive due to Permission denied: this code work successfully on python 3.8, 3,7